# I don't understand how to solve this multivariable calculus taylor series question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Question:

find the Taylor series of $f(x,y) = 1 / (2 + xy^2) $ around the point $(0,0)$

Answer:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^n y^{2n}}{2^{n + 1}}
$$

When I derive the function at $f(0,0)$ i only get that all derivatives are equal to $0,$ so I am definitely doing something wrong here. Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \frac 1 {2 + xy^2} = \frac{1/2}{1 + \frac{xy^2} 2} = \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 {1-r} \\[6pt]
& \big(\text{where } r = - xy^2/2\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \left( 1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + \cdots \right).
\end{align}

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$\left. \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x^k} \right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} = \left.\frac{(-1)^k k! y^k}{(xy+2)^{k+1}}\right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} = 0$$

$$\left. \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y^k} \right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} = \left. \frac{(-1)^k k! x^k}{(xy+2)^{k+1}} \right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} = 0$$

$$\left. \frac{\partial }{\partial y^i} \frac{\partial }{\partial y^i} f(x,y)\right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} = \left. \frac{ (i!)^2}{(xy+2)^{2i+1}} \left((-1)^i2^i + f(i) \sum_{j=1}^i (xy)^j \right) \right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} =  \frac{(-1)^i(i!)^2}{2^{i+1}}$$

So you'll need to test the other possibilities. But, observe that not all of the combinations are 0.